# Django - Filter queryset after appending to it

Tags: python, django

I would like to filter a query set after I have added to it. See below

**view.py**

```
documents = Document.objects.all()

for document in documents:
  document.hello = "Hello"
  # Lots more happens here like carrying out more querying and appending things on to document

drawings = documents.filter(type='d')
schedules = documents.filter(type='s')

# Context.... render... etc..
```

**template**

```
{% for document in drawings %}

<p>{{document.hello}}</p>

{% endfor %}

{% for document in schedules %}

<p>{{document.hello}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

The problem I'm having is the information appended (like the 'Hello') are being lost when carrying out the filter. If I do the following all works fine.

```
{% for document in documents %}

<p>{{document.hello}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

How do I transfer the appended information through the filter. Should I use a custom template filter instead of doing it in the view?

Thanks

Comment: `filter()` always means going back to the database. Why can't you do your changes *after* the filters?

Comment: That was my initial plan but I have 5 document types so I had to repeat the document in documents part 5 times which is not very DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` will create new queryset object. Instead of it you can filter with Python:

```
for document in documents:
  document.hello = "Hello"
  # Lots more happens here like carrying out more querying and appending things on to document

drawings = [document for document in documents if document.type == 'd']
schedules = [document for document in documents if document.type == 's']
context = {'documents': documents, 'drawings': drawings, 'schedules': schedules}
```

You need to add new lists to context to use them in template:

```
{% for document in drawings %}

<p>{{document.hello}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

**UPD**

Or instead of it you probably want to use [`annotation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value

documents=Document.objects.annotate(hello=Value('hello',output_field=CharField()))
drawings=documents.filter(type='d')
schedules=documents.filter(type='s')
```

Comment: How is this different from the OP's queries already? Instead of passing a queryset to the template engine, you're now just passing lists to it instead?

Comment: @JonClements New lists supposed to be passed with context. I've updated answer.

Comment: However, you can just pass the queryset objects as context?

Comment: @JonClements hm.. But in this case hello attribute will be lost. Well, I think it would be better to use annotation in this case. I updated answer with this option. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this. The first part with the new list is working well. Just a quick question, I need to do an 'and' statement. [x for x in y if a==1 and b==1] but that bit isn't working. I won't be able to use the annotations as what I am appending to the query is complex involving vast for and while loops.

Comment: @Spinnaay `if a==1 and b==1` should work fine. Can you post what you try?